# C++ find_first_not_of

Tags: c++

Im a c++ beginner and I'm getting confused with this one, any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "CONVERSION\n\n";
    cout << "Base 11 to Decimal\n";
    cout << "Base 11: ";
    getline(std::cin, str);
    const auto bad_loc = str.find_first_not_of("0123456789aA");
    if (bad_loc != std::string::npos) 
    {
        throw "bad input"; // or whatever handling
    }
    unsigned long ul = std::stoul(str, nullptr, 11);
    cout << "Decimal: " << ul << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output was

```
CONVERSION

Base 11 to Decimal
Base 11: 1234AB
```

The program stopped and it didn't send me the "bad input". Couldn't find any solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well you don't catch and handle the thrown string. So your program will just exit, and your OS will do whatever it does, which may not include attempting to print the string. For the purposes of this test, it's probably simpler to replace `throw "bad input";` with `std::cerr << "bad input\n"; return 1;`.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working now my problem is looping it :D thank you so much.

Comment: @BoBTFish could you transfer your comment into a answer so that the question can be marked as answered please?

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it's rare that beginners post MCVEs in which you don't have to manually add all the includes and `using`s or `std::`s, and such behaviour should be rewarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BoBTFish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171191/bobtfish) gave the answer in a comment:

> Well you don't catch and handle the thrown string. So your program
>   will just exit, and your OS will do whatever it does, which may not
>   include attempting to print the string. For the purposes of this test,
>   it's probably simpler to replace
>
> ```
> throw "bad input";
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> std::cerr << "bad input\n";
> return 1;
> ```

Comment: I'm writing bobtfish's comment in an answer so this question can be marked as answered. If @BobTFish wants to write the answer himself (as I think he should have done in the first place), I'll gladly delete it.